# How to map string id, index and value in a nested python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

If a data is presented as a dictionary:

```
dct = {'s1': "MP", 's2': "GP", 's3': "MP"}
```

but I want to map corresponding position of each value according to their indices in such a way that I should get:

```
{0: {'s1': "M", 's2': "G", 's3': "M"}, 1: {'s1': "P", 's2': "P", 's3': "P"}}
```

How should I go about it in python?

I tried to decompose the original dict in standard way and used `enumerate()` method as so:

```
# create a variable to store a nested dict
IndexDict = {}
# decompose the original dict 
for key, value in  dct.iteritems():
    #print key
    #print value
    for i, v in enumerate(value):
       #print i
       #print v
       # my attempt here to create a nested dict of the form {0:{s1:"M",S2:"G", s3:"M"},1:{s1:"P",s2:"P",s3:"P"}} fails!
       IndexDict[i][key] = v

 # printIndexDict returns an error
```

Comment: What happens if the strings are not of equal length?

Comment: For a quick solution, instead of doing `IndexDict[i][key] = v`, use `IndexDict.setdefault(i, {})[key] = v`. You may also want to take a look at `collections.defaultdict`.

Comment: The strings are aligned and should be of equal length

Comment: @Andrea Corbellini that was really quick and works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the nested dictionary to hold the key-character pairs for a given index, if it isn't already present. You can do so with a `defaultdict()` or using `dict.setdefault()`.

Using the [`dict.setdefault()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
IndexDict = {}
for key, value in  dct.iteritems():
    for i, v in enumerate(value):
       IndexDict.setdefault(i, {})[key] = v
```

The method adds the second argument as a value if the first argument, a key, is not present, then returns the value for the key (which is the new object or the already existing one).

Or with a [`collections.defaultdict()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

IndexDict = defaultdict(dict)
for key, value in  dct.iteritems():
    for i, v in enumerate(value):
       IndexDict[i][key] = v
```

`defaultdict` is a subclass of `dict` that calls the factory argument given to it if a key is missing; here that is `dict()` so if `i` is not present a new dictionary is added for you.

Demo:

```
>>> dct = {'s1': "MP", 's2': "GP", 's3': "MP"}
>>> IndexDict = {}
>>> for key, value in  dct.iteritems():
...     for i, v in enumerate(value):
...        IndexDict.setdefault(i, {})[key] = v
... 
>>> IndexDict
{0: {'s3': 'M', 's2': 'G', 's1': 'M'}, 1: {'s3': 'P', 's2': 'P', 's1': 'P'}}
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> IndexDict = defaultdict(dict)
>>> for key, value in  dct.iteritems():
...     for i, v in enumerate(value):
...        IndexDict[i][key] = v
... 
>>> IndexDict
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {0: {'s3': 'M', 's2': 'G', 's1': 'M'}, 1: {'s3': 'P', 's2': 'P', 's1': 'P'}})
```